# SSRS- The window when you edit expressions does not show the button ok and cancel and the button help only shows half

Tags: reporting-services, window, expression

[enter image description here][1]

It only happens in the expressions window on ssrs (see the picture below). I try to change resolution and scale without success. Can you help?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOovb.png

Comment: What is the native resolution of your display? What Resolution do you have set in Windows? What scaling settings do you have? Typically you need to match the resolution to the native resolution and use the recommended scaling (the options will show "(recommended)" next to them)

Comment: Are you using something like surface or the likes? I have the same problem but only on the surface :/

Comment: Yes I have a yoga

Comment: Alan Schofield, I have the resolution and scale recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The expression window has a minimum height so it's not fitting with your resolution. You can navigate to the OK button using your keyboard. When you're done entering your expression hit the `Tab` key 5 times and then press `Enter`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but in my pc it doesn't work. I have yoga pc lenovo 910-13ikb

Comment: In what way does it not work? Your `Tab` key doesn't work? The selection doesn't move when you press it? Is it selecting a different button after 5 presses?

Comment: Yes, After 5 presses the selection move 5 times forward. It doesn't move to the ok button.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and my solution was to go to the file located at

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Report Builder\15.0.0.0\user.config

and change the values in the MainWindowSize field to match the resolution values for my main display. That brought the OK button back for me. The buttons aren't fully there, so there's still some weirdness around scaling, but at least I can view and click on the OK and Cancel buttons now.